# a-animation discards initial model rotation

Tags: aframe, gltf

I'm using AR (with marker) and animating a gltf model to rotate on one axis counterclockwise. Initially put my marker on the table and had the model rotate slowly 360 on its vertical axis:

https://codepen.io/germanviscuso/pen/rvVomR

(you can test the actual AR tracking if you have a [hiro marker](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/blob/master/doc/patterns/Hiro%20pattern.pdf) handy)

Now I need to put the marker on a deck (slides) for people to try on a wall but need to keep the same animation (you first see the face then the back of the head then face again) but the initial model rotation `(-90 0 0)` (as you can see in the demo above) is not taken into account by `a-animation`. It would seem that the `a-animation` coordinates are absolute rather than relative to the initial rotation of the model. If I remove the whole `a-animation` the initial rotation looks good but the model is of course static.

How should I fix this? What is the right way to apply the same animation but relative to the initial rotation of the model? (I need to start the animation from `rotation=(-90 0 0)`, rotate on the vertical axis (now parallel to the marker) and end in the same place)

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation -- a-animation is deprecated.

You can set the animation from to `-90 0 0` and rotate to for example `-90 360 0`.

Or put the rotation in a parent.

```
<a-entity animation="property: object3D.rotation.y; from: 0; to: 360; loop: true">
  <a-entity gltf-model=""></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```